# iPhone app crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I've had three users of an app I've published say that it crashes. I've run it in Instruments and there are no leaks and no over released objects either. I've been using the app myself quite a bit for at least 2 weeks and it doesn't crash for me.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to problem solve an issue like this.

One thing that I'm suspicious of is the Millenial Media ads that I have running in some of the views. A Build and Analyze reveals 13 issues and they all pertain to the ad API

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: If your code is 100 % clean than the problem is the AD API. Are you able to edit the API?

Comment: yes I can edit the AD API. quick question - if Instruments show no leaks, no red color allocation issues and build and analyze shows no problems on my end can I assume my code is clean? Would those tools have caught anything that would cause a crash? I'm new at this so I naturally have to assume the error is on my end.

Comment: It could be possible that somewhere in your code is something that insturments/..etc won't detect and it would cause a crash in the rarely situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure out the cause of a crash is to get hold of the crash reports from the affected iPhones. Anything else will just be guesswork.
Either you might be able to have the users send you a crash report or you will have to sit it out until enough users are affected and it shows up in iTunesConnect. The last one is not really an option if you want to have a bugfix out quickly since there are several reports that says the you might need as much as over 100 crash reports before it actually shows up in iTunesConnect.

To solve this problem in the future (not going to do much for your current bug) is to install QuincyKit. It'll send you the crash reports directly from the affected iPhones the next time your app is launched. You can either have this as a hosted solution at [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/) or you can host this yourself for free. QuincyKit is available for download from [GitHub](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit).